# CDO 'mergetime' got warning and how can I verify the output file isn't corrupted?

Tags: linux, cdo-climate

I tried the following command in CDO for combining different time slices of a few CMIP6 outputs in one file. I got a warning that I listed below and at the same time, I got a merged output. How can I verify the output isn't corrupted? I am a very new CDO user, I will appreciate your suggestion in making my learning process easier. Thanks!

I tried following:

```
cdo mergetime pr_day_CESM2-WACCM-FV2_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_19891222-19991231.nc pr_day_CESM2-WACCM-FV2_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_20000101-20100110.nc pr_day_CESM2-WACCM-FV2_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_20091212-20150101.nc merged.nc
```

I got this:

Warning (cdfInqContents): Coordinates variable time can't be assigned!
Warning (cdfInqContents): Coordinates variable time can't be assigned!
Warning (cdfInqContents): Coordinates variable time can't be assigned!
cdo   mergetime: Processed 3 variables over 9166 timesteps [49.27s 76MB]

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that you're trying to merge overlapping timesteps. So first you have to adjust dates in consecutive order. I believe then your merge will be completed.